# OAuth from Outlook Add-in on mac

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I am trying to perform OAuth from an React based outlook add-in (running on mac) and I'm running into some trouble. I have a node/express backend with an endpoint to perform the OAuth handshake but how do I 1) open a browser or pop-up window from my front end add in? and 2) how do I get the token back to the front end app if control is transferred to another browser or pop-up window?

Comment: Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync() is your friend. Check out the docs here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync?product=outlook. We have some samples there as well.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll take a look